# Web Scraping using VBA with Selenium

Tags: vba, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am a begginer using Selenium in VBA for web scraping, but i had to change my code because the webpage was not working with IE. My code already open the webpage, change the view and order of the resuts... and I only need the products name, price, info and seller to be scrape to my sheet "RESULTADO". I only can get it for the first product... but i can not make it work for each of the element of the result. It appear to be a problem with the tyo of class or name of class... but i have realy tried with all that i could imagine. PLEASE HELP...

```
    'CHROME
Const sURL As String = "https://mercadolibre.com.mx"
Dim bot As New ChromeDriver
Dim Catal As Long
Dim FinCatal As Long
Dim VarA As String
Dim myproducts As WebElements
Dim myproduct As WebElement
Dim i As Integer
Dim mysheet As Worksheet
With bot
    .get sURL
End With
bot.Window.Maximize

'choose product from catalogue
Sheets("CATALOGO").Select
For Catal = 2 To 1048576
    If Cells(Catal, 2) = "" Then
    FinCatal = Catal - 1
    Catal = 1048576
    Else
    VarA = Cells(Catal, 3)
    
    'search product in webpage
    bot.findElementByName("as_word").SendKeys VarA
    bot.FindElementByClass("nav-search-btn").Click
    
    'wait
    Do Until InStr(1, bot.Url, "listado") > 0
        Application.Wait (DateAdd("s", 1, Now))
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    'change view
    bot.FindElementByClass("view-options-buttons").Click
    
    'wait
    Do Until InStr(1, bot.Url, "DisplayType") > 0
        Application.Wait (DateAdd("s", 1, Now))
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    'order by lower price
    bot.FindElementByClass("ui-dropdown__link").Click
    bot.findElementByLinkText("Menor precio").Click
    
    'wait
    Do Until InStr(1, bot.Url, "PRICE") > 0
        Application.Wait (DateAdd("s", 1, Now))
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    'scrape products, price, info and seller
    Set mysheet = Sheets("RESULTADO")
    
    i = 1
    Set myproducts = bot.FindElementsByClass("results-item highlighted article stack product ")
    For Each myproduct In myproducts
        mysheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = bot.FindElementByClass("main-title").Text
        mysheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = bot.FindElementByClass("item__price").Text
        mysheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = bot.FindElementByClass("stack-item-info").Text
        mysheet.Cells(i, 4).Value = bot.FindElementByClass("item__brand-title-tos").Text
        i = i + 1
    Next
    
    End If
Next
```

Comment: it would help to provide a couple of example input values and the associated results for input value. As results may vary over time screenshots with highlighting of desired elements is often useful. And OFC, check scraping is allowed first in the terms and conditions.

Comment: Thank you... the problem is really in the last part of the code. I have my variable myprudycts that are all the elemnts but at the end it only has the first data... so i know my For Each is ok... the problem is  here 'bot.FindElementsByClass("results-item highlighted article stack product ")' but i have tried other classes with out luck. It will be great if yoyu coud enter the page and check this... please

Comment: I need a search so as to get results. Please provide a search term.

Comment: THIS IS AN EXAMPLE OF A PRODUCT THAT I WOULD SEARCH FOR CRAPING: Compresor Goni De 2.5 Hp Con Tanque De 25 Litros - Model 960